# How to assign Application Pools to different ASP.Net Core web sites in AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: powershell, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We have two ASP.Net Core 3.1 websites (with different domain names/host headers) deployed in Elastic Beanstalk running Windows 2019 Core server and IIS. We were able to do this by following https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/multi-app-support-with-custom-domains-for-net-and-aws-elastic-beanstalk/

However, both the websites are running under 'DefaultAppPool'. ASP.Net Core does not allow more than one application per application pool (HTTP Error 500.35 - ASP.NET Core does not support multiple apps in the same app pool).

So, we added the following section to aws-windows-deployment-manifest.json

```
"iisConfig": {
    "appPools": [
      {
        "name": "AppPool1",
        "managedPipelineMode": "Integrated",
        "managedRuntimeVersion": "v4.0"
      },
      {
        "name": "AppPool2",
        "managedPipelineMode": "Integrated",
        "managedRuntimeVersion": "v4.0"
      }
    ]
  }
```

And, EB deployment created corresponding app pools in IIS.

Now, we are not able to assign the app pool to each web site. Ideally, we'd like to use commands from WebAdministration module (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadministration/?view=windowsserver2019-ps) in 'install*.ps1' PowerShell scripts or in a '.config' file in '.ebextensions' folder. However, the web administration module is not available in either place and
`IMPORT-MODULE WebAdministration` doesn't work either. Only the IISAdministration module (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iisadministration/?view=windowsserver2019-ps) is available at the time 'install*.ps1' scripts are executed.

So, how to assign application pools to different ASP.Net Core websites in AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very lightly documented (for Windows Server) secret sauce is hiding at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platform-hooks.html

So, for us the following strategy worked. We added the following contents in  apppool.config (name doesn't matter as long as it has .config extension) file to .ebextensions

```
files:
  "c:/Program Files/Amazon/ElasticBeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/config.ps1":
    content: |
      Start-IISCommitDelay
      $site = Get-IISSite "site1"
      $site.Applications["/"].ApplicationPoolName = "AppPool1"
      $site = Get-IISSite "site2"
      $site.Applications["/"].ApplicationPoolName = "AppPool2"
      Stop-IISCommitDelay
```

This created a powershell script `config.ps1` in `c:/Program Files/Amazon/ElasticBeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/` folder. The powershell script executes after a new instance is created or a new version is deployed.

The only shortcoming is `config.ps1` is created every time new version is deployed on an existing instance. It doesn't hurt as old file is renamed to `config.ps1.bak` and is ignored by EB deployment process. There is definitely room for improvement here (will defer for another day).

For the sake of completion, here's entire `aws-windows-deployment-manifest.json`

```
{
  "manifestVersion": 1,
  "iisConfig": {
    "appPools": [
      {
        "name": "AppPool1",
        "managedPipelineMode": "Integrated",
        "managedRuntimeVersion": "v4.0"
      },
      {
        "name": "AppPool2",
        "managedPipelineMode": "Integrated",
        "managedRuntimeVersion": "v4.0"
      }
    ]
  },
  "deployments": {
    "custom": [
      {
        "name": "site1",        
        "scripts": {
          "install": {
            "file": "install1.ps1"
          },
          "restart": {
            "file": "restart.ps1"
          },
          "uninstall": {
            "file": "uninstall1.ps1"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "site2",        
        "scripts": {
          "install": {
            "file": "install2.ps1"
          },
          "restart": {
            "file": "restart.ps1"
          },
          "uninstall": {
            "file": "uninstall2.ps1"
          }
        }
      }  
    ]
  }
}
```

And Here's `install1.ps1`

```
Copy-Item -Path "C:\staging\site1" -Destination "C:\inetpub" -Recurse -Force
New-IISSite -Name "site1" -BindingInformation "*:80:*.site1.com" -PhysicalPath "C:\inetpub\site1" -Force
```

And `uninstall1.ps1`

```
Remove-IISSite -Name "site1" -Confirm:$False
rm -r "c:\inetpub\site1" -Force
```

And `restart.ps1`

```
iisreset /timeout:1
```

`install2.ps1` and `uninstall2.ps1` are similar to their site1 counterpart, as above.

We have referred to a lot of articles online and owe a `Thank You` to all of them.

Answer (score 1):

After you define the `appPools` in the manifest file, you can assign them to your apps using their `appPool` property:

```
{
    "manifestVersion": 1,
    "iisConfig": {
        "appPools": [
            {
              "name": "AppPool1",
              "managedPipelineMode": "Integrated",
              "managedRuntimeVersion": "v4.0"
            },
            {
              "name": "AppPool2",
              "managedPipelineMode": "Integrated",
              "managedRuntimeVersion": "v4.0"
            }
          ]
    },
    "deployments": {
        "aspNetCoreWeb": [
            {
                "name": "frontend",
                "parameters": {
                    "appBundle": "./frontend",
                    "iisPath": "/frontend",
                    "appPool": "AppPool1"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ext-api",
                "parameters": {
                    "appBundle": "./ext-api",
                    "iisPath": "/ext-api",
                    "appPool": "AppPool2"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Georgi for your inputs. But, this configuration can not be used if anyone wants to use different domain name for each application (as in my case). Upon further research, I figured out how to do this last night. I'll post it as an answer to this question.